# Capturing bluetooth traffic to and from the computer

Tags: bluetooth, wireshark, packet-capture

May i ask if it's possible to capture Bluetooth traffic to and from the computer (MacOS, Windows or linux)?
Since i am trying to use wireshark to capture traffic but having no sign for success of capturing the bluetooth traffic.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without adapters on Linux, but requires [additional configuration](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Bluetooth) with [bluez](http://www.bluez.org/) (and the necessary bluetooth hardware).

There are also [commercial peripherals available](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/4313/what-is-a-good-solution-to-capture-bluetooth-traffic/) from multiple vendors that may support your OS.